# Magento quick search results displaying all on one page

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch

I'm currently developing a website for a client, which seems to have created a problem for itself... Or I have, but I can't figure out where or how?!

Basically, using the quick search, it will display all the results on the same page.... Even if there are 3,000 results!

The pagination is set up correctly, for both grid & list. The toolbar displays the amount of pages there should be, yet still displays all results on the single page.

Layered navigation is set up and showing.

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to display URL's on here, but if I am an example search is here: http://dev.cblsupplies.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=63&q=light

As you can, it's having a negative impact on performance due to the vast amount of results!

I'm really stumped on this one, I've searched and searched for a resolution - but I'm unable to find one. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: A modification made by the theme might be the issue. Can you check if it created a module folder and if so, what is the module doing?

Comment: Where exactly would I be searching for this module folder? It was working fine, when I checked it about a week ago. I've been working on a different section of the site and came back to the search results today. That is when I noticed the issue.

Comment: app/code/[local,community]

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the toolbar block does not add limit to the sql query. For example because some other block load the collection *before* the toolbar.

Search for `$collection->getSize();`

Or similar method calls. At the background they may init sql query that returns not paginated results

Comment: Ok, so I can't see any reference to `getSize();` - I disabled the current theme, and tested it with another. It works perfectly. So it's definitely something to do with the theme! Now time to dig a bit deeper.

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helps )

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on `catalog.xml` file in the location `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml`. The handles that you need to study are `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered`. The following code snippet is taken from `catalog_category_default`. The same portion is also awailable for the handle `catalog_category_layered`.

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
        <!--
            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
        -->
    </block>
    ...
</block>
```

This is what our default `toolbar` block definition. Now look on those actions that are commented out inside `toolbar` block. The method that we interested here is `addPageLimit`. This method is used to set page limit for `toolbar` block. In order to test it, you need to edit your theme's `catalog.xml` file. In that file, if this section exists, just add this codes there

```
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
<action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
```

Samething you  need to do for the handle `catalog_category_layered`. Then clear cache and try again.

You can also take a look on my [**blog**](http://rajeev-k-tomy.blogspot.in/2014/07/set-page-size-for-particular-category.html) which teaches **how can we set page size via observer**. You can get that extension through [**github**](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/magento-set-page-size).

**Note:** Make sure cache is cleared before refresh the page.

Hope it helps for you.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I've given that a shot, but unfortunately it's made no difference to the result output. I can't understand what's made it mess up like this. It was working perfectly last week. I've disabled all new modules that have been implemented since then, but still nothing. It's really puzzling me!

Comment: did you try my extension ?